# Point when the tangent line has slope zero

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The figure below shows the graph of $f(x) = x^5-8x^3+1$

[image]

The two marked points are at a local max and min.

The curve in the figure has one point whose tangent line is horizontal even though the point itself is neither a max nor a min. Find the (x,y) coordinates of that point.

If the tangent line is horizontal, doesn't that mean that the derivative is 0 at that point?

So i need to find at which point the derivative is 0?

$f'(x)= 5x^4-24x^2$

$0=x^2(5x^2-24)$

$x=0$ is the point since the other two points are the max and min. Plugging this back into $f(x)$ gives 1, so the point is $(0,1)$. 
Is this correct?

Comment: Yep. It is correct.

Comment: Yep.  Basic calculus.

Comment: If those thin lines are meant to be the coordinate axes, then the curve in the illustration is _not_ the graph of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is basic calculus.  Here are the graphs:

[image]

An inflection point occurs when the first *and second* derivatives vanish and that is indeed at $(0,1)$.

[image]

[Click on animation]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is indeed correct. This type of point is called a horizontal point of inflection.